# C# run a file with different extension as a child .exe

Tags: c#, process, spawn

Hey I want to do the following:

I have a file named file.tmp and I want to run it as an exe.
That won't work with `process.start("file.tmp")` as it gives me an error message "wrong file archive".

Instead I have to do:

```
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("file.tmp");
 info.UseShellExecute = false;
 Process processChild = Process.Start(info);
```

But because of that the file will be started as seperate process, but I want to run it as a child to the c# loader that I am running it with.

Is there any other method I could use?

Comment: yes sorry my bad. UseShellExecute should be false instead of true. edited it.

Comment: I'm confused by what you're expecting. You say it's started as a separate process, which is true (it's what `Process.Start` *does*), but also that you want to run it as a child, which is also the case (it will be run as a child process). What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @canton7 Hey I have a c# loader which should start the file.tmp as a child process so if I check the parent of the file.tmp it should be the c# loader and not the cmd or shell window which would be the case with useshellexecute.

Comment: Right, but you're setting `UseShellExecute` to `false`, so the shell won't be the parent. Your loader application will be the parent process.

Comment: @canton7 It is not in my case. If I open up task manager the file.tmp has no parents and shows up as standalone instead of being a child of the c#loader.exe

Comment: Screenshot? I don't remember Task Manager being good at showing parent/child relationships between processes. Process Explorer does show it well however.

Comment: Sure but If I check the parent process from the file.tmps sourcecode (coded in c++) it shows me that it doesn't have any parent. just like it displays in task manager. So I wonder if there is a different approach.

Comment: Again, add this information to your question. You might be doing something wrong there, but we can't tell based on the information we have

Comment: @canton7 and again the question is if there is a different approach then the one I wrote above, instead of asking how to fix the current approach which doesn't work for me which I tried several times already.

Comment: The current approach *does* start the other process as a child. I have personally done this many times, and in situations where the parent/child relationship mattered, so I'm certain this works as expected. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @BaseultBusiness when your process starts another, your process is the parent. That's it. What is your *actual* problem and what did you expect? Did you expect it to terminate if the parent terminated? From [Terminating a Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/terminating-a-process) : `When the system is terminating a process, it does not terminate any child processes that the process has created.`. Did you expect the child process to inherit the parent's environment? That's already done

Comment: @BaseultBusiness `If I check the parent process from the file.tmps sourcecode (coded in c++)` what does your C++ code do? What problem did you encounter that made you look into child process issues?